# Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58848/BJZ_ZgFILrE=/ws

Tags: flutter, dart

Everytime I run the command `flutter run` , I get this log

```
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58848/BJZ_ZgFILrE=/ws
```

is it possible to make the port `58848` fixed?
if not, how to get this URL after hot reload ( it does not print on hot reload and hot restart)

Comment: It wont change on hot reload, just refresh the tree

Comment: Yes, but where else can I obtain this value apart from log at launch ? (the logs gets deleted after reload and restart)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to define a fixed port:

```
 flutter run --observatory-port=33221
```

Then you can access your profiler on that port.

```
 An Observatory debugger and profiler on yourDevice is available at: http://127.0.0.1:33221/XG9ySnxn3XU=/
```

Read more from [here](https://medium.com/flutter/profiling-flutter-applications-using-the-timeline-a1a434964af3).